# Java Screen Resolution Size

Tags: java, swing, jframe, resolution

I need some direction on this project that I am creating.  I am currently trying to create a JFrame that automatically opens to the resolution of the screen.  I have looked online for help with this aspect of the project and I have found multiple ways to do it.  After doing even more research on the methods through the API and reference code of how to use the methods I have put together some code.  When I run my program I get a window that pops up like this...  (not full screen...)

[image: Program Results]

I would appreciate some pointers on where I messed up, I would prefer help in the way of tips or tricks but I will accept code as well (sorry just trying to learn and not copy code).  Thank you for your time.

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.Frame;

public class Window {

private static int ScreenWidth;
private static int ScreenHeight;

public int getWidth(){
    return  ScreenHeight;
}

public int getLength(){
    return ScreenHeight;
}

public void WindowSetup(){
    Dimension UserScreen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int ScreenWidth = (int) UserScreen.getWidth();
    int ScreenHeight = (int) UserScreen.getHeight();
}

static void CreateJframe(){
    JFrame gui  = new JFrame("Changeable Resolution");
    gui.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(gui.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    gui.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight));
    gui.pack();
    gui.setVisible(true);

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Window window = new Window();
    Window.CreateJframe();      
}
```

}

Comment: See [`Frame.setExtendedState(state)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setExtendedState-int-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You never call `WindowSetup`
2. You assign the results of `getScreenSize` to local variables
3. Then you call `pack`...`pack` uses the preferred size of the content, not the window, to make decisions about who best to size the window.

So that ain't going to work...

The simplest way would be to use `JFrame#setExtendedState` and pass it `JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH`

```
JFrame gui = new JFrame("Changeable Resolution");
gui.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(gui.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
gui.pack();
gui.setVisible(true);
```

Now, you might be saying, but I want to cover the taskbar...

In which case you could try something more like...

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();

GraphicsConfiguration gc = gd.getDefaultConfiguration();
Rectangle bounds = gc.getBounds();

JFrame gui = new JFrame("Changeable Resolution");
gui.setSize(bounds.width, bounds.height);
gui.setLocation(bounds.x, bounds.y);
gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(gui.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
gui.setVisible(true);
```

But you'll probably find that the task bar doesn't like been covered, in that case, you would need to resort to full screen exclusive mode...

See [Full-Screen Exclusive Mode API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/) for more details...

Comment: Thank you for your help again MadProgrammer.  Always enjoy the answers you give and all of the things I learn and can research into more!!!

Comment: @MichaelShoenberger Self education, the cornerstone to complete confusion...I mean madness, I mean awesomeness ;)

Comment: Yeah I have experienced that to a slight degree so far.  :P  I still have found self educating a better way for me personally to learn when it comes to programming in comparison to the many classes I have taken.

Comment: @MichaelShoenberger Sometimes you just have to jump in the puddle to get muddy ;) - Learn Objective C and I've taught my self more in the last week then the 3 classes I've had so far...sometimes, you just need that push...